# How to make Mocha unit test wait for async variable

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, mongoose, mocha.js

I am very new to unit testing and I am trying to write a unit test on a function that reads from my database, but because the read is asynchronous the value is always undefined in my Mocha unit test. How can I do an assert on a variable which is declared asynchronously?

Unit Test:

```
const homeController = require('../controllers/homeController');

describe('Testing home_get function', function () {
  it ('should render the home page', function () {
    const req = {};
    homeController.home_get(req, null, () =>  {});
    console.log("numberUsers", numberUsers);
    assert.ok(numberUsers > 0);
  });
});
```

Function I am trying to test:

```
module.exports.home_get = async (req, res) => {
    requestTime = Date.now();
    numberUsers = await User.countDocuments({});
    numberViewers = await Viewer.countDocuments({});
    numberAccreditors = await Accreditor.countDocuments({});
    
    res.status('200').render('home', {numberUsers: numberUsers, numberViewers: numberViewers, numberAccreditors: numberAccreditors});
};
```

When I do an assert statement on the requestTime variable it works as intended but when I do it on the async variables the value is always undefined and I am not sure how to get the unit test to work on these async variables, also.... how would you then do a unit test to check the res.status is correct when you render home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main goal in unit testing is to only test 1 layer of logic, such as the function itself you have presented. every other thing must be a mock, otherwise it is an integration test that you require and not a unit test.

in this case, you are trying to actually run a query on a database, but it is not actually up and working, so what you get is undefined.

i suggest the following:

1. if you want to actually query the database, run an integration test instead where it will actually work. integration tests are loading the whole application to test the interaction between all of the components.
2. to complete the unit test itself, you should mock the database such as it returns what you expect it to return, so only those 5 lines in the function is actually running.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been looking into integration testing and have made some progress with it :) 

`describe('GET /home', () => {
  it('should get home with status 200', done => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get('/home')
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
      });
  });
});`


However, the res.body is undefined and I was hoping of testing the variables being passed e.g  numberUsers
I have got bodyParser included as search said this may be problem, not sure why else it wouldn't work

Comment: i would use a library called supertest which makes it simpler to test API calls end to end, and make sure the DB is up and running when you run it locally. you will have to run a container for it and pass the local authentication configs

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to do that.

You can await your function in the test:

```js
  it ('should render the home page', async function () {
    const req = {};
    await homeController.home_get(req, null, () =>  {});
    console.log("numberUsers", numberUsers);
    assert.ok(numberUsers > 0);
  });
```

or use the test callback function:

```
  it ('should render the home page', function (done) {
    const req = {};
    homeController.home_get(req, null, () =>  {}).then(() => {
      console.log("numberUsers", numberUsers);
      assert.ok(numberUsers > 0);
      done();
    });
  });
```

But in either case your function should return a value on which you can make the assert. There, the `numberUsers` is never declared and will still be `undefined`.

edit: Except if registered in the `globals` object because not using `let`, `const` or `var`. This is something you probably do not want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

Your code works but it's not performing as I was hoping for because as mentioned below I need to use integration testing for it to perform how I wish.....  I still found your feedback to be very helpful though :)